# When does insetting a polygon produce a similar one?

Tags: polygons, similitude

Consider the operation of insetting every side of a polygon by a fixed perpendicular distance, as illustrated (for example) at https://alienryderflex.com/polygon_inset/. For which polygons does this operation produce a similar polygon (for at least some interval of inset distances)?

For example, it does for all regular polygons, all triangles, and all kites (and hence rhombuses) -- intuitively because an instance of each of these families is determined up to similarity by its vertex angles, which are preserved by the insetting operation. But it definitely does not for all polygons -- not the example in the link above, nor for any non-square rectangles. Is there a characterization of polygons for which insets are similar?

Comment: I think you've already mentioned the key property. If a class of polygons has the property that they are determined up to similarity by their vertex angles, then offsetting a member of the class will produce a similar triangle, provided the offset was not so large as to completely remove a side. But classes of polygons that do not have this property will not produce similar polygons when offset.

Comment: "But classes of polygons that do not have this property will not produce similar polygons when offset." -- Do you have an argument for that? Certainly some polygons that are not in a class with this property don't remain similar when inset. But why would _all_ such not? Also how is this a property of a polygon -- after all, a rhombus is in the class of "quadrilaterals", and "quadrilaterals" do not have the property that they are determined by their vertex angles, yet rhombuses remain similar when inset. So, given a specific polygon, how do you determine if it has the inset-similarity property?

Comment: My brother (who faced a real-world tiling problem that led to this question) floated the idea that all of the angle bisectors of the vertex angles of the polygon meeting at a single point might be a sufficient condition to be inset-similar. Certainly when insetting a polygon, the new vertex corresponding to each old one ends up on the angle bisector at that vertex; and all of the examples in the original post have that property. But we don't have a proof of either sufficiency or necessity of this condition.

Comment: Rhombuses constitute a class of polygons that are determined up to similarity by their angles. Any such class is a subset of a larger class that doesn't have the property - in particular, the class of all polygons lacks the property. I did not mean that membership in any class without the property on the whole automatically disqualified a polygon. I also didn't mean it as a solution to your question - to my mind it just pushes the question down a level. But it might help focus on what is important. Maybe "can be disected into congruent triangles"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My brother completed the proof, which he said he preferred I post.

**Claim**: A polygon is inset-similar (even for just one inset) iff it is *tangential* (i.e., has an inscribed circle).

Proof: It is pretty straightforward that a tangential polygon is inset-similar for any inset less than its inradius: scale by an appropriate factor about the incenter, and all the new edges are the same distance from the original ones.

Now, given a polygon which is inset-similar by an inset $h_1$, let the ratio of similarity of the inset polygon to the original be $r<1$. Then scaling down the diagram of the original and inset polygon by factor of $r$, we see there is an inset $h_2$ at which the original polygon is also inset-similar, but this time with a scale factor of $r^2$. Repeating, we get a sequence of inset polygons at insets $h_i$ at scale factor $r^i$. Now notice that the vertices of each of these inset polygons lie on the angle bisectors of the original vertex angles. Since $r^i \to 0$, these angle bisectors must all meet at a point. Hence, by a well-known theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangential_polygon) the original polygon is tangential. (And it turns out its inradius is the limit of the $h_i$.)